# bcrypt.compare retornando false mesmo com senha correta após certo período de tempo

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

Estou usando o `bcrypt` para gerar hash de senha no Node.js, conforme código abaixo, após criar um usuário:

```
UserSchema.pre("save", async function(next) {
  const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.pass, 8);
  this.pass = hash;
  next();
});
```

Porém, ao fazer login, a função de verificação usa o método `compare` do `bcrypt`, e após um tempo, passa a retornar `false` mesmo estando com a senha correta, a princípio funciona, mas ao passar algumas horas, às vezes dias, para de retornar `true` e retorna `false`. O código de verificação está abaixo:

```
let userExists = await User.findOne({ name });
  if (userExists) {
      const password = await bcrypt.compare(pass, userExists.pass);
      if(password) console.log(password);
  }
```

Alguém sabe me informar se existe uma inconsistência com o `bcrypt`? Estou usando a versão 2.4.3.

Para teste, criei um usuário com nome 'a' com senha '123456' e seu hash gerado foi `$2a$08$M.WZbdMKOFjPCQBp0iYAf.cENIWvMV.4efgCqWPjwoXrIP97Iv.Fm`, retornou `true` em um período de 3 horas, após isso, passa a retornar `false` com a mesma senha.

Criei outros usuários, alguns demoraram dias para retornar `false`. Mas sempre há esse erro, de um tempo para de funcionar.

Comment: Esse pacote está bem estável eu uso ele! deve ser algo no seu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugiro essa edição:

```js
userSchema.pre('save', async function () {
  if (this.isModified('password')) {
    this.password = await User.hash(this.password)
  }
})
userSchema.statics.hash = function(password) {
  return bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
}
userSchema.methods.matchesPassword = function(this, password) {
  return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password)
}
// ...
const user = await User.findOne({ email })
if (!(await user.matchesPassword(password))) {
    throw new Error('Senha Incorreta')
}
```